# Replacing AppDomain in Net Core

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

So, I am new in C# and Net Core, and someone passed me code to an evaluate command.
However, it wasn't made in Net Core, so, the AppDomain doesn't exist in Net Core,what should I do?

```
ScriptOptions so = ScriptOptions.Default;

            so = so.WithImports(new string[] { "System.Math", "System.Diagnostics", "System.Runtime.InteropServices",
            "Discord.WebSocket", "Discord.Commands", "Discord", "System.Threading.Tasks", "System.Linq", "System", "System.Collections.Generic", "System.Convert", "System.Reflection"});
            so = so.WithReferences(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(xa => !xa.IsDynamic && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xa.Location)));
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `AppDoamain` in .net core you can use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` library to achieve what you need.

Below is code from an [article](http://www.michael-whelan.net/replacing-appdomain-in-dotnet-core/). You can see full details there.

```
return GetReferencingLibraries("Specify")
.SelectMany(assembly => assembly.ExportedTypes);

public static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetReferencingAssemblies(string assemblyName)
{
    var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    var dependencies = DependencyContext.Default.RuntimeLibraries;
    foreach (var library in dependencies)
    {
        if (IsCandidateLibrary(library, assemblyName))
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(library.Name));
            assemblies.Add(assembly);
        }
    }
    return assemblies;
}

private static bool IsCandidateLibrary(RuntimeLibrary library, assemblyName)
{
    return library.Name == (assemblyName)
        || library.Dependencies.Any(d => d.Name.StartsWith(assemblyName));
}
```

You will need to include `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` package to use above code.

Comment: Just to clarify AppDomain hasn't vanished in entirety as [it is part of .Net Standard 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600956/465053).